# Use a recent version of Perl to write scripts for an older version

Tags: perl, compatibility

When I put `use v5.8;` at the top of my script, this means the script will not run unless it's being interpreted by Perl 5.8 or better. My question is, is there a way to force Perl to run in "compatibility mode" for a specific version? So that if I use a (fictitious) line like `use only::v5.8;`, my script will not run if it uses language features that weren't present in Perl 5.8.

My use case is that I would like to be able to develop scripts for my work machine (which has an older Perl release) using my personal laptop which has a more recent one.

Comment: It would be far more reliable to simply install the older version on your work machine. `perlbrew` makes that easy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [Perl::MinimumVersion](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::MinimumVersion) and [Perl::MinimumVersion::Fast](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl::MinimumVersion::Fast) on CPAN.

For the former there is also a [command line tool](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlver).

With those modules you can check if your program needs a more recent perl version. Sadly the formatting is a little of.

```
perlver yourfile.pl



   -----------------------------------------  
 | file       | explicit | syntax | external |
 | ----------------------------------------- |
 | logfile.pl | v5.10.0  | v5.6.0 | n/a      |
 | ----------------------------------------- |
 | Minimum explicit version : v5.10.0                       |
 | Minimum syntax version   : v5.6.0                        |
 | Minimum version of perl  : v5.10.0                       |
   -----------------------------------------
```